# react native - redux state cause performance issues

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am new in both React native and redux. While I am working with React native and redux, I realize that `state` in redux `store` cause the `component` render a lot.

For example, I have data of a list view which is stored as a redux state. The list view will be shown in screen A. For some reasons, I will modify the list view in next screen. By storing the data in redux state, the list view in screen A will auto update whenever there is a change of the list view in the next screen.

Unfortunately, I have to re-render every components in screen A whenever the data in list view is changed (If I put the data in component state, only the list view will be re-rendered instead of all components).

Can I store the data of list view in redux state and just re-render it (not all components)?

If you have any suggestion, please let me know.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you have some code to show?

Comment: @Dherik: thank you for considering my question. I will make a simple code and edit the question as soon as possible.

Comment: @Dherik: the answer of Kuby is great. I can solve my problem now. Thank you all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if you have connected the state to properties with `mapStateToProps`, then whenever you change the data in the `reducer`, these `props` are changed too and this causes re-calling the `render()` method, so basicly re-render.

Every connected `props` from the `state` are causing re-render of the components, if they are changed in the `reducers store`.

In your case, the problem should be somewhere else, maybe in the navigator, that leaves the component A after navigating from A to B still mounted in the background?

To answer your question, you can store your data of `ListView` (some json list) in `redux`, and than `connect` it with your component, but try to make another component inside the `Component A`, like `Component A_2` and connect this with  `mapStateToProps`. Then if you change the data, only the `Component A_2` will be re-rendered, not the whole `Component A`.

Comment: Please correct the english of this answer. Also use `` to make variables look like `this`. Try to add some formatting to make the answer more readable

Comment: This is the best english I can do, sorry. I edited the highlights, is it better now?

Comment: @kuby: Thank you, this is the solution for my case